# Remove Mandrill unsubscribe link

Tags: mandrill, unsubscribe

Is there any way in Mandrill to remove their unsubscribe link :  `*unsubscribe from this list*` & use just mine  : `*|UNSUB:http://mywebsite.com/unsub|*` ?

Comment: I guess you're looking for this, but on reverse: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583017-Can-I-add-an-automatic-unsubscribe-link-to-Mandrill-emails- - so if you're putting one in yourself, Mandrill may remove the one that it inserts automatically.

Comment: yes I read that, & I tested it but the email still received with their generated link of unsubscribe !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the mandrillapp > settings > sending defaults you can disable the setting of mandrill to add an unsubscribe footer.

Then add your own link in the html or text of the mail message.